# XSLT - XML to fixed position flat file

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0, xslt-3.0

Required is a fixed position, flat file.

Input file holds records with descriptions in two languages. My XSLT works fine, padding is applied when shorter values are present. Except, when there are no translations available, the padding is not applied.

Following input :

1. Element 1 has no translations
2. Element 2 has one translation
3. Element 3 has both translations

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<CSKS_Records>
  <Record>
    <BUKRS>2510</BUKRS>
    <KOKRS>A000</KOKRS>
    <KOSTL>0001000900</KOSTL>
  </Record>
  <Record>
    <BUKRS>2510</BUKRS>
    <KOKRS>A000</KOKRS>
    <KOSTL>0010009000</KOSTL>
    <Record>
      <SPRAS>N</SPRAS>
      <KOKRS>A000</KOKRS>
      <KOSTL>0010009000</KOSTL>
      <KTEXT>Centrale - General M</KTEXT>
    </Record>
  </Record>
  <Record>
    <BUKRS>2510</BUKRS>
    <KOKRS>A000</KOKRS>
    <KOSTL>0025101101</KOSTL>
    <Record>
      <SPRAS>N</SPRAS>
      <KOKRS>A000</KOKRS>
      <KOSTL>0025101101</KOSTL>
      <KTEXT>Fin. admin. (BE)</KTEXT>
    </Record>
    <Record>
      <SPRAS>F</SPRAS>
      <KOKRS>A000</KOKRS>
      <KOSTL>0025101101</KOSTL>
      <KTEXT>Compta. fin. (BE)</KTEXT>
    </Record>
  </Record>
</CSKS_Records>
```

[XSLT Fiddle](https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/pNXUzKg)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml"  omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
    <!-- remove white space nodes -->
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <!-- In XSLT 3.0, specify the fallback behaviour -->
    <!-- Causes all nodes that are not matched (including text nodes) to be skipped -->
    <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-skip"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/CSKS_Records">
    <xsl:text>COg  Kostenpl.  Description                    Omschrijving                   BECR *</xsl:text>
    <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:for-each select="Record">
              <xsl:value-of select="substring(concat(BUKRS,'     '),1,5)"/>
              <xsl:value-of select="substring(concat(format-number(KOSTL, '#'),'           '),1,11)"/>
              <!-- unescape XML characters like &gt; or &amp; -->
              <xsl:value-of select="substring(concat(./Record[SPRAS eq 'F']/KTEXT,'                               '),1,31)" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
              <xsl:value-of select="substring(concat(./Record[SPRAS eq 'N']/KTEXT,'                               '),1,31)" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
              <xsl:text>     </xsl:text>
              <xsl:text>*</xsl:text>
              <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Result

```
COg  Kostenpl.  Description                    Omschrijving                   BECR *
2510 1000900         *
2510 10009000                                  Centrale - General M                *
2510 25101101   Compta. fin. (BE)              Fin. admin. (BE)                    *
```

Required result

```
COg  Kostenpl.  Description                    Omschrijving                   BECR *
2510 1000900                                                                       *
2510 10009000                                  Centrale - General M                *
2510 25101101   Compta. fin. (BE)              Fin. admin. (BE)                    *
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that `xsl:output method="text"` is more appropriate and also fixes the issue. You can then also drop the disable-output-escaping.

Comment: So easy, I overlooked that - excellent!